# Unable to resolve the image to URL: to_model delegated to the attachment, but the attachment is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attachment, rails-activestorage

I have a problem with active_storage that I cannot solve, maybe some of you have experienced these kinds of problems and could help me :

- I have two different Devise => `Users` (= pros) and `Parents` (= parents)
- Each `pro` have `one_attached :avatar`
- On the parents’ home page, I can access to all parameters of `pros` and display them except for the `avatar`

=> I can display something like this `# <ActiveStorage :: Attached :: One: 0x00007fcf70e75918>` when I pass `<% = @pro.avatar %>`

=> But with `<% = image_tag @pro.avatar %>` I get this error `Unable to resolve the image to URL: to_model delegated to the attachment, but the attachment is nil` and  Rails confirm that there is no attachment but in `pro_model` and the views of `pros_controller` I can get this attachment.

Does anyone know why and might have a solution that could help me ?
Thanks you for your help !

pros_controller :
`def pro_params
    params.require(:pro).permit(
      :avatar,` etc..

Pro_model:
`has_one_attached :avatar`

Parents_controller :

```
def home
  @pros = Pro.all
end
```

My code is in other controller and is :

```
<% ip_pro_eajes = @pros.where.not(pro_type: "Assistante Maternelle").geocoded.near("Paris")%>
    <% Pro.first.avatar %>
    <% ip_pro_eajes[0..2].each do |pro_near| %>
      <li class="pro-nearby" id="aeje-nearby">
        <%= image_tag url_for(pro_near.avatar.attachment) %>
         <%= pro_near.avatar.attached? %>
         <p style="color: #6EBEB4; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400"><%= pro_near.pro_type.upcase %></p>
        <p style="font-size: 19px; font-weight: 400"><%= pro_near.company_name %></p>
        <p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 400"><%= pro_near.address %></p>
      </li>
   <% end %>
```

I used `pro_near` in the iteration to get all parameters of `@pro` but only `:avatar` is unavailable
When I try`<% Pro.first.avatar %>` , attachment is nil as well

Answer (score 0):

Could you give the output of the inspect method on `@pro`?

Try to format your question a bit like that:
[Can't resolve image into URL: to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487780/cant-resolve-image-into-url-to-model-delegated-to-attachment-but-attachment-i)

Comment: Is these details help you to better understand ?

Comment: It could have been helpful to have some tests on this. Would you mind showing a rails console output? 

What does Pro.first.inspect prints?
Pro.first.avatar.attached?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= image_tag(@pro.avatar) if @pro.avatar.attached?%>
```

refer [this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html)

Comment: Thank you, I know this kind of controls but my pros have attachments and I need to display them so I really don't want to filters non attachment I just need to find the solution to display them in an other controller, all others parameters are available but not avatar as nil but I know that it is not nil in the reality